# Which's the real androidmanifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, manifest, declare

I'm using [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) to create a very very simple app.

But I don't know (about editting the manifestandroid.xml) where to change, if it is at the one inside the bin file or the one on the root file. Seeing them now I can notice they are diferent by one activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components and settings of an Android application are described in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `ROOT`-directory. This file is known as the Android manifest file.

All activities, services and content providers components of the application must be statically declared in this file. Broadcast receiver can be defined statically in the manifest file or dynamically at runtime in the application.

The Android manifest file must also contain the required permissions for the application. For example, if the application requires network access, it must be specified here.

Manifest in `BIN`-directory is the result of the `manifestmerger.enabled` property.
You can use it to merge library project manifest files into the including project's manifest. The resulting manifest will be in your `BIN`-directory.

Also... The only `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to worry about is the one in your root project directory. It is real `AndroidManifest.xml`-file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the one in the root directory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's one on the root file. (AndroidManifest.xml)